# Does the additional attack from the Gloom Stalker ranger's Dread Ambusher feature stack with Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, ranger, stacking

The [Gloom Stalker Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#GloomStalker) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* gets the Dread Ambusher feature at level 3, which says (pg. 42):

> At the start of your first turn of each combat, you walking speed increases by 10 feet, which lasts until the end of that turn. **If you take the Attack action on that turn, you can make one additional weapon attack as part of that action**. If that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d8 damage of that weapon's damage type.

Rangers also get [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#ExtraAttack-301) at level 5 (PHB, pg. 92):

> Beginning at 5th level, **you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action** on your turn.

So, for a 5th-level Gloom Stalker Ranger, since both class features involve taking the Attack action, do I have to pick whether to make my extra attack with the Dread Ambusher feature *or* the Extra Attack feature ([similar to how a monster with Multiattack has to choose "Multiattack" instead of the standard "Attack" action](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/58396/35259)) or do I effectively get 3 attacks, like a level 11 Fighter (but only on my first turn, obviously)?

Comment: Very Related [Ranger Whirlwind Attack vs Extra Attack and Horde Breaker](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46528/ranger-whirlwind-attack-vs-extra-attack-and-horde-breaker)

Comment: Related: [How does a Gloom Stalker's Dread Ambusher's timing interact with Extra Attack?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128040)

Comment: Related: [Does the Gloom Stalker ranger's Dread Ambusher feature grant a separate attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139774/does-the-gloom-stalker-rangers-dread-ambusher-feature-grant-a-separate-attack)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## It stacks

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

If you take the attack action, you attack twice.

> At the start of your first turn of each combat, you walking speed increases by 10 feet, which lasts until the end of that turn. **If you take the Attack action on that turn, you can make one additional weapon attack as part of that action.** If that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d8 damage of that weapon's damage type.

If you take the attack action, you can make one extra attack.

Nothing in these two statements prevents the other. One changes your number of attacks to a flat number (2), the other says "whatever it was before, +1".

2+1 = 3, you get three attacks in the first round of combat, and one of those 3 attacks deals extra damage. You get only 2 attacks for the rest of the combat.

**On multiattack:**
Multiattack is a monster specific action. It is NOT the 'Attack action', it's a specific action some monsters have, that determines what it can do with those attacks. This is to prevent, for example, a bandit captain from using its multiattack to make three grapple attempts in a single round. Both your features require the 'Attack action'.

Comment: You might also make the argument that ruling that they don't stack means the feature doesn't do anything, which would obviously be wrong.