# How does a Gloom Stalker's Dread Ambusher's timing interact with Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, ranger

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126130).

The [Gloom Stalker Ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#GloomStalker) from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* gets the Dread Ambusher feature at level 3, which says (pg. 42):

> At the start of your first turn of each combat, you walking speed increases by 10 feet, which lasts until the end of that turn. **If you take the Attack action on that turn, you can make one additional weapon attack as part of that action**. If that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d8 damage of that weapon's damage type.

Rangers also get [Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#ExtraAttack) at level 5 (PHB, pg. 92):

> Beginning at 5th level, **you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action** on your turn.

**How do Dread Ambusher and Extra Attack interact in terms of the order in which they must be made, if any exists?**

Comment: Related: [Does the Gloom Stalker ranger's Dread Ambusher feature grant a separate attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139774/does-the-gloom-stalker-rangers-dread-ambusher-feature-grant-a-separate-attack)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The Dread Ambusher attack can be taken at any point in the Attack action after the first attack

[Dread Ambusher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#GloomStalker) says:

> At the start of your first turn of each combat, you walking speed increases by 10 feet, which lasts until the end of that turn. If you take the Attack action on that turn, **you can make one additional weapon attack as part of that action**. If that attack hits, the target takes an extra 1d8 damage of that weapon's damage type. (XGE 42)

Note that nowhere does it specify any timing restrictions on the attack. Specifically, the wording does not specify or even imply that the extra attack happens after or even as a result of the Attack action. In fact, it says the attack is made *as part of* the Attack action.

To take the Attack action you must actually attack something, so that means you must use one of your normal attacks first. After that, it doesn't matter where you insert the Dread Ambusher attack.

This is supported by the fact that the ability says you get an "additional" attack this implies at least one other attack has already happened.

There are no rules dictating what order you must take attacks in when you have more than one in the same Action so there is no reason to think that this is not the choice of the person doing the attacking.

#### Extra Attack has no bearing on the ruling

In this case, Extra Attack actually has no bearing on the issue.

[Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#ExtraAttack) says:

> Beginning at 5th level, you can attack twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on Your Turn. (PHB 92)

Extra Attack does not insert any kind of restrictions or specifics about timing of attacks. Thus, the answer is the same if you are taking a single attack as part of an Attack action or if you have the Extra Attack feature: the Dread Ambusher attack can come at any point in the action after the first attack.

#### This ruling has very little impact

The only impact that I can think of for this ruling is that it allows the player to roll a potentially higher damage attack roll sooner in the turn. The only obvious advantage to which would be that it would have a higher chance of killing the creature outright and thus saving on wasted attacks.

Otherwise, there really seems to be nothing here that would impact the game in any significant way.

Comment: @Medix2: If the resulting attack was not part of the self-same Attack action, then it *would* imply that the Attack action needs to be completed first. However, the fact that the resulting attack is part of the Attack action (and thus the Attack action can't complete without the DA attack) means that no such timing interpretation is possible.

Comment: There is actually one way in how the timing matters, and that is if you first use your normal attacks to make a creature go prone, you could then use your extra attack to get advantage. That said, this is also the case for any situation where you must first attack and then get a bonus action, so it's not a situation where you can make things far more beneficial by using your bonus first, like it would in for the Shield Master prone-with-bonus-action effect.

Comment: I think you could actually declare the extra attack from Gloom Stalker as your first attack.  The order really doesn't matter so long as this special attack is declared before rolling.  I think there is various Sage Advice and/or tweets that would back that up if someone wants to dig them up.

Comment: @NickBrown: I assume Rubiksmoose's interpretation is that you have to attack in order to be taking the Attack action. I'd add that "one additional attack" implies that you have to have made an attack to begin with.

Comment: @V2Blast However there are other times that we see "additional" used such as with Action Surge and *haste* and one wouldn't argue that *hate's* action must come after your regular one, or that Action Surge's action must come after your regular one (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156932)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose You say "To take the Attack action you must actually attack something" but then why does the Monk's Fangs of the Fire Snake feature benefit the first attack when it says "**When you use the Attack action** on your turn... Your reach with your unarmed strikes increases by 10 feet for that action, as well as the rest of the turn" (thus you have used the Attack action *before* making the first attack) Similarly the Battle Master Fighter's Commander's Strike Maneuver states "**When you take the Attack action** on your turn, you can forgo one of your attacks..."

Comment: @Medix2 I *think* the first could be simply explained by specific over general maybe? If I'm understanding you correctly. Actually the second even more so. It's also possible that this is just a case of inconsistent wording (in 5e?!). I'm not entirely sure I find them convincing that it is true in general. Though, I really will think more about it.

Answer (score 2):

The "Attack" action is an turn category, not an action in itself. To say that you must make your first attack before you're officially taking the attack action would literally mean that you're employing the combat mechanic of the attack before actually declaring the attack. I think for most players, it's not standard practice to differentiate between the declaration of the action and the execution of the action. So the wording of the feature is confusing. Mechanically speaking, the correct progression of the turn would be to declare your intention to take the attack action (as opposed to taking the cast action, or taking the dodge action, etc) and then commencing with the attack phase of your turn. Once you've declared your attack action, you're in it and the order by which you execute your various attack abilities should be up to the player's discretion.