# Can you take the additional action from the fighter's Action Surge feature before you take your regular action?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, actions, fighter

The fighter's [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ActionSurge-193) feature (post errata mentioned in the [2019 Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=3)) now states:

> On your turn, you can take one additional action.

The [Eldritch Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight) gets the [Arcane Charge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#ArcaneCharge-224) feature (PHB, p. 75), which states:

> At 15th level, you gain the ability to teleport up to 30 feet to an unoccupied space you can see when you use your Action Surge. You can teleport before or after the additional action.

Are you allowed to take Action Surge's "additional" action, thus allowing you to use Arcane Charge, and *then* take your regular action?

If you have to use your normal action first, then your options are Action --> Teleport --> Action Surge and Action --> Action Surge --> Teleport. If you can use Action Surge first, this gives you the new option of Teleport --> Action Surge --> Action.

Comment: Am I missing why it would matter?

Comment: @NautArch it determines whether you can teleport or not. For example: Attack action, Teleport, Attack action is different from Teleport, Attack action, Attack action. I've edited it in now

Comment: Why are there ellipses in the Arcane Charge description? Isn't that the entire text of the feature?

Comment: @ryanthompson I wasn't sure honestly, I found the quote on another question in two pieces and haven't had access to the wording, I'll remove it

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because after further consideration I'm no longer convinced of the argument in it (that "additional" can't be the first action), since I don't think I or anyone else would reasonably apply the same logic to *Haste*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes, you can Action Surge before taking your first action.

In the PHB, Action Surge doesn't mention a condition of using your Action Surge aside from being on your turn. If it had said, "after using your action" this wouldn't work, but because it has no such specifier, you can use your Action Surge before your original action.